# Write the equation $4x^{2}+4z^{2}=5$ in spherical coordinates.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

Write the equation $4x^{2}+4z^{2}=5$ in spherical coordinates.

I used the facts that

$$
\begin{align}
x&=ρ\sin\theta\cos\phi\;,\\
z&=ρ\cos\phi\;,
\end{align}
$$

And ended up with:

$ 4 (ρ^2 \sin^2(\phi) \cos(\theta) + ρ^2\cos^2(\phi))= 5 $

But it's not simplified enough? I can't use Pythagoras' theorem: $\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta) = 1$ inside the parenthesis.

So what do?

Comment: How are you defining $\phi$ and $\theta$? Is $\phi$ measured from the positive z-axis (positive being upwards) and $\theta$ measured from the positive x-axis (positive being the standard convention of to the right)?

Comment: isn't ϕ positive downwards? http://i.imgur.com/y5S4XPQ.png (pi/3 in this case) Although, ϕ from 0 to 2pi, after it reaches pi, wouldn't it start going upwards at the other side of the ... well, sphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you define spherical coordinates that ultimately determines what the equation looks like. If you define spherical coordinates like this

$$x = \rho \sin \theta \cos \phi$$
$$y = \rho \sin \theta \sin \phi$$
$$z = \rho \cos \theta$$

where $\rho$ is the radius, $\theta$ is the inclination, and $\phi$ is the azimuth. Naturally, $\rho \in [0, \infty), \> \theta \in [0, \pi], \> \phi \in [0, 2 \pi]$.

(notice that the cosines are different for x and z unlike in your definition, although I think this is what you meant)

then

$$\rho^2(\cos^2 \phi \sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta) = \frac{5}{4} $$
$$\rho^2(\cos^2 \phi \sin^2 \theta + 1 - \sin^2 \theta) = \frac{5}{4} $$
$$\rho^2(\sin^2\theta(\cos^2 \phi -1) + 1) = \frac{5}{4}$$
$$\rho^2(1 - \sin^2 \theta \sin^2 \phi) = \frac{5}{4}$$

is the simplest. However, you do not have to define spherical coordinates in such a manner.

This convention is used more often in physics where in mathematics you would often see $\theta$ and $\phi$ be flipped in definition.

Comment: simplest would be $\rho^2(1-\sin^4\theta)=\frac{5}{4}$

Comment: do you mean $\rho^2 (1 - \sin^2 \theta \sin^2 \phi) = \frac{5}{4}$

Comment: oh, yeah... forget my dysgraphia

Comment: no worries. I'll add this to the answer

Comment: @TnilkImaniq I don't know why you switched θ with ф, but sure, thanks for heads up.

Comment: @Jack I was matching your notation in the question. You stated you define x as $\rho \sin \theta \cos \phi$ which only makes sense if $\theta$ and $\phi$ are defined as I did. Otherwise, x would equal $\rho \sin \phi \cos \theta$